# Como exibir dados de um script Node.js em uma página HTML

Tags: html, node.js

Gostaria de saber como eu posso executar um script Node.js em uma página HTML. O script é um *crawler*, ou seja, ele puxa dados de uma página e eu gostaria de exibir as informações que ele trouxer. Gostaria de saber também, se existe alguma função parecida para HTML. Obrigado!

Comment: Pergunta: por que tem que ser executado no servidor? Não pode executar no próprio HTML?

Comment: Olá Cigano. Então tem que ser executado no servidor por causa do node.js, eu estou tentando achar alternativas para executar direto no html, porém não encontro.

Comment: Na verdade você precisa combinar [a resposta do @Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207065/2999) com alguma forma de o HTML chamar um método no servidor, como usar um *endpoint* do Express.js.

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez, vou tentar.

Answer (score 2):

Existem alguns crawlers na NPM/Github, um deles o `simplecrawler` que costumo usar.

Um script que eu uso é:

```js
var domain = 'http://teu.dominio.com/';
var Crawler = require("simplecrawler");
var fs = require('node-fs');
var url = require('url');
var path = require("path");

new Crawler(domain).on("fetchcomplete", function(queueItem, responseBuffer, response) {

  var parsed = url.parse(queueItem.url);
  if (parsed.pathname === "/") {
    parsed.pathname = "/index.html";
  }

  // Diretoria de destino
  var outputDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'tua_pasta');

  var dirname = outputDirectory + parsed.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, "");
  var filepath = outputDirectory + parsed.pathname;
  fs.exists(dirname, function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
      fs.writeFile(filepath, responseBuffer, 'utf8', function() {});
    } else {
      fs.mkdir(dirname, 0755, true, function() {
        fs.writeFile(filepath, responseBuffer, function() {});
      });
    }

  });

}).start();
```

Precisas configurar o dominio, e a pasta de destino, de resto é só correr o ficheiro.

Comment: Olá Sergio. Obrigado pela resposta, tem como eu executar esse script direto no html? Obrigado!